How to convert a map to vars
In short, given a map with an arbitrary number of elements, for example:
{
  key1 = "val1",
  key2 = "val2"
}

I want to turn each of the elements into variables (convert a map to vars or locals):
var.key1 = "val1"
var.key2 = "val2"

But without writing a file to disk. The only way I could find was to write each key out to a .tfvars file.
The use case is that I have a module (say "modules/myresource") that looks like
variable "setting1" {
  type = string
}

variable "setting2" {
  type = string
  default = ""
}

resource "someresource" "somename" {
  setting1 = var.setting1
  setting2 = var.setting2
}

And then a YAML file (resource1.yaml)
resource1:
  settings:
    setting1: value_of_s1
    setting2: value_of_s2

which I want to use to configure someresource.somename by loading the settings with yamldecode and passing them to the module. But there are potentially hundreds of settings and not all of them would be defined in the yaml file, so I want to do this without having to define each setting in my module {} block.
So, instead of:
locals {
  resource_settings = yamldecode(file("resource1.yaml"))["settings"]
}

module "myresource1" {
  source = "./modules/myresource"
  setting1 = local.resource_settings["setting1"]
  setting2 = local.resource_settings["setting2"]
}

I want something like:
locals {
  resource_settings = yamldecode(file("resource1.yaml"))["settings"]
}

module "myresource1" {
  source = "./modules/myresource"

  for_each = local.resource_settings
  {each.key} = each.value
}

That's obviously not going to work, but hopefully it clarifies what I'm after a bit.

Does the resource someresource take more than one setting at a time?

Is the initial map of input variables in JSON format a file or theoretical? You mention the variable values are stored in a YAML file, and are also a JSON map. Do you need both or only one for the values? Is the module with the variable declarations the root module or a declared module?

I tried to add a bit more clarity to the use case.
